# Where is Visual C++ on Windows after install?

Tags: visual-studio

I have installed Visual C++ on Win7 (virtual machine) but cannot find it. First I ran the setup exe file and then I tried to find VS in the 'Program Files' and 'Program Files' directory but it's not there (the installer said it's installed). I've even tried to search it but with no success. Uninstalling and re-installing doesn't help either. I've even read [this](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/support/vs2015/cannot-find-visual-studio-2015-start-menu/) article form Microsoft but didn't help. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I assume you mean 2017. Its here on my laptop: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\"

Comment: If all else fail, you can search for devenv.exe...

Comment: I checked the Program Files (x86) directory and it's not there.